# Is it possible to use a QML Singleton as a header Item inside a QML Page?

Tags: qt, qml

I have a `StackView` that displays several pages of type "`TabletPage.qml`" :

```
// TabletPage.qml
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQml.Models 2.1

// import TopBar.Singleton 1.0

Page {
    id: root

    property ObjectModel menuBarModel

    signal homePageRequested()
    signal backPageRequested()
    signal pageRequested(string url)
    signal pageRequestedWithProp(string url, var prop)

    width: Screen.width
    height: Screen.height

    background: Rectangle { color: "black" }

    header: TopBar {} // Ok but each Page has its own TopBar
    // header : TopBarSingleton // -> crash the UI, does not work

    footer: HorizontalMenuBar { model: root.menuBarModel }
}
```

Each `TabletPage` has its own footer (a custom QML component `HorizontalMenuBar`) and a header (a custom QML `TopBar`) but now i need to make the header "global" : all pages should refer to the same QML instance of `TopBar.qml`. I have tried to make the `TopBar` a Singleton (using the `qmlRegisterSingletonType` method) but how then i can refer to it in the header of each `Page` ?

Is the singleton approach even possible in this case ?

Thank you.

Comment: Are all the pages instantiated from the same place? If so, you could set the `header` property from that central place to a single `TopBar` (not singleton, but one instance)

Comment: They are not actually, but as a workaround in the same spirit, i have not defined TopBar as a header in a Page anymore. Instead it is instantiated once within the same scope of the StackView that is simply anchored to the bottom of the TopBar.